# Maven - Not able to open jars it is downloading

Tags: maven, jar, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

Whenever I try to run `mvn clean install` on my code, maven runs and start downloading jars, after downloading some jars It give an error i.e. Not able to open `xxxxx.jar` 
On first though i changed that particular jar , but this error is coming for more jars, then i tried to take my friends repository.

And then it works fine for the jars already available in my friends repository. But whenever it have to download new jars from central repository same error occurs.

I tried 100 of time deleting **.m2** folder and create it again but no luck.

I also tried switching maven installations or version from different friend and maven official websites but still No Luck

I am fed up of this. Trying from last week.

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick suggestion from the top of my head:

You could take a look at the .jar-Files that get downloaded using a text editor or even better some hex-editor. Depending on the network from that you are accessing the repository there might be some kind of proxy-server that intercepts the jar-download-requests and sends back some html-page - at least it might do so in our company-network.

If the text-editor just shows some strange characters try opening the jar-file with some zip-tool (eg. 7zip) and see if that shows some error.

Comment: Hi piet.t , Yes I tried the same using Zip Editor, while opening I am getting an error i.e. Invalid File :(

Comment: ...what about the text-editor? Just some binary noise?

Comment: Following Below is text getting when trying to open maven-clean-plugin in text editor, (Here i get build failure with the error [ERROR] Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-cle
an-plugin:2.4.1 (C:\Users\Saurabh_Khirbat\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugin
s\maven-clean-plugin\2.4.1\maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.jar): error in opening zip f
ile -> [Help 1])

<HTML>

</frameset>
</html>

It is giving some HTML files

Comment: You should try opening the downloaded *jar*-file (in your local .m2-folder) with a text editor. If everything went well there shouldn't be any readable content, but if there is it might give a hint what went wrong.

Comment: getting readable copyright information and html file while opening in text editor

Comment: Sounds a bit like the case I described above. So you'll have to try to identify who is sending the html-file (e.g. by looking at the copyright-information). If it is a proxy-server at your company try talking to the proxy-administrator if you can somehow bypass this mechanism.